# delphi - how to get type of enum

Tags: delphi, types, enums, delphi-xe2

I know how to get enum value from integer value, and I have this code

```
function GetEnumValue(intValue:integer):TMyType
begin
   if(ordValue >= Ord(Low(TMyType)))and(ordValue <= Ord(High(TMyType)))then 
      result :=TMyType(ordValue)
   else 
      raise Exception.Create('ordValue out of TMyType range');
end;
```

I have similiar code like above in many place for many enum type other than TMyType, I want encapsulate that code to single protected code on base class, so inherited class can use it.

but I dont know how to generalize TMyType, so my code can check if it right enum type or another type object

I cant have a clue what a enum base class (like TObject for all of object type or TControl for all of VCL type), then I can check like that code

Comment: Which version of Delphi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as a base type for an enumeration type, like TObject is the base for classes.

If you have a Delphi version that supports generics, you can use following helper to make a generic cast from an ordinal value to an enumeration value.

```
uses
  System.SysUtils,TypInfo;

Type
  TEnumHelp<TEnum> = record
  type
    ETEnumHelpError = class(Exception);
    class function Cast(const Value: Integer): TEnum; static;
  end;

class function TEnumHelp<TEnum>.Cast(const Value: Integer): TEnum;
var
  typeInf  : PTypeInfo;
  typeData : PTypeData;
begin
  typeInf := PTypeInfo(TypeInfo(TEnum));
  if (typeInf = nil) or (typeInf^.Kind <> tkEnumeration) then
    raise ETEnumHelpError.Create('Not an enumeration type');
  typeData := GetTypeData(typeInf);
  if (Value < typeData^.MinValue) then
    raise ETEnumHelpError.CreateFmt('%d is below min value [%d]',[Value,typeData^.MinValue])
  else
  if (Value > typeData^.MaxValue) then
    raise ETEnumHelpError.CreateFmt('%d is above max value [%d]',[Value,typeData^.MaxValue]);
  case Sizeof(TEnum) of
    1: pByte(@Result)^ := Value;
    2: pWord(@Result)^ := Value;
    4: pCardinal(@Result)^ := Value;
  end;
end;
```

Example:

```
Type
  TestEnum = (aA,bB,cC);

var
  e : TestEnum;
...
e := TEnumHelp<TestEnum>.Cast(2);  // e = cC
```

---

There is one limitation:

Enumerations that are discontiguous or does not start with zero,
have no `RTTI` TypeInfo information. See [`RTTI properties not returned for fixed enumerations: is it a bug?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7857981/576719).

Comment: you save my day...thanks alot...that I looking for, so hard to find reference like this, and lucky me I use XE2

Comment: I would make the Cast method generic and not the type.

Comment: @StefanGlienke, you mean `TEnumHelp.Cast<TEnum>(Value : Integer)`. What are the advantages for that?

Comment: The advantage is that you can write the Cast method in a non generic way passing in the `PTypeInfo` and don't get generic types generated for every enum type.