# Why does my C++Builder 'enum' not work correctly with RTTI

Tags: enums, c++builder, rtti

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get “type has no typeinfo” error with an enum type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420562/why-do-i-get-type-has-no-typeinfo-error-with-an-enum-type)

I have a component with a property like this:-

```
enum class Foo {VAL0, VAL1, VAL2, VAL4 =4};

class TDummy : public TComponent
{
...
  Foo f;
  TDummy() : f(Foo:VAL2) {};

__published: 
  __property Foo foo{ read = f, write = f};
}
```

However, when installed, the IDE object instpector doesn't give me a dropdown list of choices for 'foo', but just displays an edit field with the value '2' in it.

How can I get the IDE to show "VAL2" instead of "2", and display a dropdown list of choices VAL0/VAL1/VAL2, etc../?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the enum values aren't contiguous. Change the enum declaration from

```
enum class Foo {VAL0, VAL1, VAL2, VAL4 =4};
```

...to...

```
enum class Foo {VAL0, VAL1, VAL2, VAL3, VAL4};
```

And the property will work correctly in the object inspector. Of course, VAL3 can now be chosen, which isn't ideal.

Delphi doesn't support non-contiguous enums, so there's no way the RTTI can represent a non-contiguous set of values.

Comment: If you cannot define an enum with contigious values, then you have to write a custom property editor instead.

Comment: Thanks. Realized the question is a duplicate, (doh!) so please vote to close.