# Enumerations (with custom values) to String / Text

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

One can use something like this to convert an enum to string:

```
uses
TypInfo;

type
  Language = (Delphi,Delphi_Prism,CBuilder);

var
  StrLanguage : String;
begin
  StrLanguage  := GetEnumName(TypeInfo(Language),integer(Delphi)) ; 
end;
```

(taken from [theroadtodelphi](https://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2009/10/27/convert-enum-to-string-using-delphi/))

Is it possible to do the same for an enum that has custom values?

Something like this:

```
type
  THotkey = (hkShift= 1, hkSpace= 3, hkEnter= 6);
```

As a workaround i am using placeholders to skip not used enums.

However that's not nice and is problematic if i have to skip huge gaps.

```
type
  THotkeys = (hkShift, hkUnused1, hkSpace, hkUnused2, hkUnused3, hkEnter);
```

Comment: See [Why do I get “type has no typeinfo” error with an enum type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1420562/576719).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your specific use case, you could use an array that relates to the enum, because **enumerated constants with a specific value do not have RTTI** as stated in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Simple_Types):

> Enumerated constants without a specific value have RTTI:
>
> ```
> type SomeEnum = (e1, e2, e3);
> ```
>
> whereas enumerated constants with a specific value, such as the
>   following, do not have RTTI:
>
> ```
> type SomeEnum = (e1 = 1, e2 = 2, e3 = 3);
> ```

You can work around this like so:

```
type
  THotkey = (hkShift, hkSpace, hkEnter);
  THotkeyValues: array[Thotkey] of Integer = (1,3,6);
```

usage:

```
ShiftKeyValue := THotkeyValues[hkShift];
```

Comment: This seems like the best approche possible!

Comment: Or just THotkeyValues: array[THotkey] of Integer = (1,3,6); which has the advantage of complaining at compile time if you add some new items to THotkey.

Comment: This is even better than the answer in the linked thread!

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez: duh forgot about that, adapted my answer, thanks!

Comment: @Tommy Yes and no. This answer doesn't directly address the question. The answer really should include a doc ref to the text that explains that enums with specified ordinals don't have RTTI. You are, understandably, more concerned with solutions to your problem than with answers to the question that you asked.

Comment: @who Can you edit you answer to include the doc ref and an excerpt?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I agree,  I focused on his real problem. I suppose the edit is not needed since you closed the question as a dupe?

Comment: I'd still add the edit. Dupes have value. If you can make this answer better then it will be more useful in the future. At the dupe I can't see any doc references.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, done as requested...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is just in your example (if I've understood what you are asking)

```
type
  THotkeys = (hkShift, hkUnused1, hkSpace, hkUnused2, hkUnused3, hkEnter);

....

var
  StrLanguage : String;
begin
  StrLanguage  := GetEnumName(TypeInfo(THotkeys),integer(hkSpace)) ;
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(integer(hkSpace)) + ' - ' + StrLanguage);
```

the result will be:

```
2 - hkSpace
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the string without using placeholders.

Comment: So, do you have to get string passing the integer value?

Comment: Yes, that's what i am trying to accomplish.